# How to choose iPhone simulator model to debug Flutter app on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator

How to choose iPhone model to debug a Flutter application using VSCode? Currently every time I debug an app, iPhoneX always starts, but I would like to choose another model, for example iPhone 8, how do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Installs the [Android iOS Emulator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DiemasMichiels.emulate) extension of vscode

Answer (score 10):

// 2022

Easy way to do this is start the simulator and from MacOS dock, right click on the simlator - > Device -> ios -> choose new simlator

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The Dart VS Code extention documentation [here](https://dartcode.org/docs/quickly-switching-between-flutter-devices/) mentions a few ways to change the device that's used.

1. Clicking on the currently selected device in the status bar [image]
2. Executing the Flutter: Select Device command
3. Pressing your custom key binding for the Flutter: Select Device command

Comment: Option #2 worked best for me, since I did not have a running emulator at the time.

Answer (score 6):

What I did was change the selected iOS device in the simulator, closing the simulator, then restarted my debugging session. The flutter app was then loaded on to the newly selected device.

I am using a Macbook Pro. So if you [right-click or two-button-click] the Simulator app -> select 'Device' -> select the iOS you want -> then select the desired device

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was running `flutter doctor` in the terminal. it gave me the following output:

```
 [!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
```

Xcode was installed previously, but after running the two commands, I was finally able to use the iOS Simulator in visual studio code.

Comment: in my case, the ios emulator option suddenly disappeared from the VSC device list. this was the solution. weird

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it's not currently possible to change which iOS device is launched in the simulator from VS Code (or the `flutter emulator` command, which uses the same code).

It seems like a neat idea though - I'd encourage raising an issue in the [flutter/flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter) repo (VS Code delegates listing and launching emulators to the Flutter tool - this allows more code to be shared across editors). Please include some info on your use cases (for example why you usually want iPhone 8 instead of X) to ensure they're considered (for example one way to avoid having a huge list of devices would be to include one iPhone, one iPad, etc. - but this might not cover your requirements).

Also - FWIW, for me the similator always loads the device that was last used.. I selected iPhone 8 and quit, then next time I launched it (from VS Code) it was still iPhone 8. Do you not see this behaviour?

Comment: Agreed, you would need to run the simulator from the command palette as you normally would, then quickly tap the device you want under Hardware > Device menus. Once your preferred device shows up, click the window of the first device that showed up and then click File > Close Window. VS Code will log something about the device terminating unexpectedly, but if you run your app again using iOS simulator, it should choose the device that's still open.

Answer (score 3):

Extension to [Danny's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57258570/8164116):

Just **start** an iOS Simulator from XCode and then you'll be able to see that specific simulator's name in the list of options (when you'll try to choose the target device).